# How to read Azure web site app settings inside RegisterServices method

Tags: azure, ninject, ninject.web.mvc, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to configure some key/value pairs for my Azure web application using *app settings* section on Windows Azure preview portal.
[image]

According to the [documentation](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-configure-websites), Azure should inject configured key/value pairs into the .Net configuration AppSettings at runtime.

Do anybody know, how to read this values inside the `RegisterServices` method of the `NinjectWebCommon` class? I tried a common way

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyWebApp.DbConnectionString"];
```

but it returns empty or null values. Reading app settings later in my web application works fine.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me.  And this may sound a tad silly... but did you explicitly Save the configuration via the save button at the bottom on the screen?  It "looks" like the values are set as you add them, but they aren't saved until you hit that button. I didn't catch that at first.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to experiment with it a little and I figured out that the problem is in Ninject MVC3 integration.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how exactly this works but the `RegisterServices` method is probably called earlier than Azure injects app settings into configuration. Fortunately, there is an alternative way to install Ninject for MVC3 that works (see [Using Binaries from Github](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application)).

Comment: +0 Pretty sure that's not going to sufficiently change the ordering of when Ninject gets initialized enough. - perhaps you're using your RegisterServices to call some startup tasks that prepare connection strings and sequencing that incorrectly?

Comment: My `RegisterServices` method contained only two rows: one for binding the `MyAppContext` class to self and second for binding the `IFacebook` interface. The first row invoked `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[]` through a simple static method, nothing more. I suspect that the problem can be caused by _WebActivator_ used by Ninject for MVC3.

Comment: Any way you could change it to use a lambda expression to get the config setting rather than doing it at the point of doign the `Bind()` ? Doing at the point of resolve should definitely make the two approaches boil down to the same thing (i.e. in a `To*` part of a Bind, you need to put in a `ctx=>` to defer the resolution to Ninject Resolve time rather than Module Load time